# Use caching in Windows Azure for Java web application

Tags: java, caching, azure-storage

I am deploying a web application developed in Java over Microsoft Windows Azure.

How to use caching in Windows Azure for Java web application at configuration level?
I don't want to write any code for caching. If there is a way to enable caching for particular  folder or particular content type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/11/05/windows-azure-plugin-for-eclipse-with-java-november-2012-preview.aspx). There is a section on configuring the cache.

Comment: I need caching on configuration level. As if we can enable caching in some xml format.